# Use basename of the file

Tags: shell, shell-command

When I am done editing myfile.tex, I `M-x shell-command RET`. At the prompt, I manually enter `pandoc -s myfile.tex -o myfile.org`.

What command will save me the trouble of having to type out the myfile part everytime? So, a command like:

`pandoc -s takethebasename.tex -o takethebasename.org`

Then I can use it on `myfile.tex`, `yourfile.tex` and `hisfile.tex`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expanding on [@NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825/nickd)'s answer, I like to do these kind of shell operations with `compile` so I can take advantage of the instantly visible window with the "compile" command's output. Taking the original example I'd do <kbd>M-x</kbd>`compile`<kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd>`pandoc -s myfile.tex -o myfile.org`<kbd>Return</kbd>. On subsequent runs I'd just do <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> to run the same command again.

But, we want something more dynamic because we're editing multiple `.tex` files. Continuing our ad-hoc theme, we can use `eval-expression`. <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(compile (format "pandoc -s %s.tex -o %s.org" (file-name-base buffer-file-name) (file-name-base buffer-file-name)))`<kbd>Return</kbd>. Now, we only have to enter this once in our session because we cause use the minibuffer history again to get back to it and run it on a new buffer with <kbd>M-:</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>. This method also "feeds" `compile`. Say I'm editing `foo.tex`, and I want to "compile" it for the first time. I'll do the previous `eval-expression`. The second time I want to "compile" I could use `eval-expression`'s minibuffer history, or I could do <kbd>M-x</kbd>`compile`<kbd>Return</kbd>, and be greeted with `compile`'s prompt: `Compile command: pandoc -s foo.tex -o foo.org`. If you've run the `eval-expression` on `bar.tex` and `baz.tex`, then you could search `compile`'s minibuffer history for their constructed statements too.

Is it a better way? No, probably not. [@NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825/nickd)'s would be the way to go. But, it's different and it shows off `eval-expression`.

Comment: Thanks. This is the closest of what I was looking forward to. :)

Answer (score 4):

Write your own function to prepare the command string as you want it and then pass it to `shell-command` for execution:

```el
(defun pandoc-it ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((basename (file-name-base (buffer-name)))
         (cmd (format "pandoc -s %s.tex -o %s.org" basename basename)))
    (shell-command cmd)))
```

and execute it with `M-x pandoc-it RET`. You can also bind it to a key.

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. Just one point. Can this all be converted into a single `shell-command`? With that, I do not need to remember the name of the function to call. I can just `M-x shell-command RET` and do up/ down arrow to pick up the command I want

Comment: No - I can't see a way to do that. It's precisely the fact that you want a *different* shell command every time (depending on the buffer you are in) that prompted this function. I would just bind it to a key since it doesn't need any arguments.

Comment: @nega's answer provides something closer to what you are asking for.

Comment: Wait - you can always do `M-x` then `up` or `down` to scroll through previous commands that you have executed. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Write a file called `Makefile` containing:

```
all: takethebasename.org otherfile.org more-space-separated-file-names.org
%.org: %.tex
⇥pandoc -s $< -o $@
```

Replace ⇥ by a tab character (press <kbd>Tab</kbd>: when editing a makefile, this will insert a tab character instead of indenting).

Then running `make` will run pandoc to generate the `.org` file(s). And that's the default command for `M-x compile`.

Explanation of the make features used here:

- `foo: bar` instructs make that to *build* the file `foo`, it needs the file `bar`. Make calls `foo` a *target* and calls `bar` a *dependency*.
- If you run `make`, it builds the first target. If you run `make target-name other-target-name`, it builds the listed targets.
- In `%.org: %.tex`, the `%` sign is a wildcard, so this allows building any `.org` file from the corresponding `.tex` file.
- Lines beginning with tab are commands to build the files. The `all` target has no commands, so `make all` only requires building the listed `.org` files and not running extra commands. Building each `.org` file requires running pandoc.
- In the command, `$<` stands for the first dependency and `$@` stands for the target.
- `make` won't run the commands if the target already exists and is more recent than the dependencies (it considers the target *up-to-date*).

`make` is usually installed by default on Unix-like systems (if not, install the `make` package). On Windows you'll need some port of Unix tools.